# How do the rails executed in bash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Today I wanted to get how do the `rails db:drop` works. How did I thought: `rails` is a name of executive file that executed by Linux system when I type `rails db:drop` and `db:drop` is an argument for this file.

This file could be created in different languages, it even could be a binary. But I suppose it is created by a Ruby. So I went to the rails repo. And start reading the code of `rails.gemspec` but did not find any hints about how do the system parses cli requests.

As I suppose the parsing of rails arguments is work of the `rake`. But where is the code that points that `rake` should be started when we call `rails`?

And what is the brief structure of `rails` execution?

There must be a `rails` file, in some directory that mentioned in the `PATH` variable. And system seek for this `rails` file, select appropriate interpreter ans start to execute code in this file.  Where is the code that create this `rails` file, and what is the code of this file itself?

Comment: This question is very broad with lots of sub-questions, most of which could be answered by just running `rails` and tracing the execution. For starters, here's the code of `rails`: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/exe/rails

Comment: Yes,  Jörg, this is the real start! Thank you.  Meanwhile I been reading `$Ruby/bin/rails` file and found this line `Gem.activate_bin_path('railties', 'rails', version)` *railities* is a real starting point.

Comment: Jörg, I already discover a chain `ruby/bin/rails -> ruby/gems/reilaties/exe/rails -> ruby/gems/reilaties/lib/rails/cli.rb`. If two files at the end could be found in rails repo, how do the first one generated?

Comment: That's just normal RubyGems installation procedure.

Comment: Yes, but this instalation procedure must know that need to reffer to the Railaites, not ActiveRecored gem. And this information is stored somewhere.

Comment: RubyGems information is stored in the gem spec.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203988/discussion-between-dmitry-dmitriev-and-jorg-w-mittag).

Answer (score 0):

File `rails` is placed in `<your_application_root>/bin/` folder. 
`bin/rails` contains someting like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../config/application', __dir__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'
```

Although, this ^ might be a little outdated, this is just what I found by quick search as an example. Better you check the file in your own application with your version of rails.

Here is some useful information about rails console utilities: 
https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html

Also, from my experience, it's good to have something like RubyMine IDE for learning Ruby on Rails: https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/download/
It's not free, but there is a 30-days trial which might be enough for understanding most of the basics of the framework. 
The main advantage of this IDE is that it has very good integration with ruby version managers such as RVM, where you can add ruby sources and rails gems to the search indexing and easily navigate to methods/files/constants/etc. definitions right from the code. This is much faster than searching/opening a particular file on GitHub.

Comment: Looks like this is really outdated information. Nevertheless I really appreciate your answer. Starting point of this journey is an Gems folder of the system. And In this folder at the `bin/rails` placed a call to the RailTies gem. And Railties gem already implement the work I asked about.

Comment: Oh, I see now. This is not outdated information. I think I just misunderstood what exactly you needed and answered a little different question lol. Good that you've figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

How to the `rails` works from the Linux shell point of view?

**"rails" command is a part of the Railties gem**

- Start `rails` file that stored at the `ruby_instalation_dir/bin`. This file is generated by [RubyGems](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/railties.gemspec#L23-L24) from the **Railties** gemsec file. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59269405/8574922)
- `rails` file is a Ruby file that calls [railaties/rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/exe/rails) file
- and the `railaties/rails` file requires [rails/cli.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/cli.rb)

Yes `rails` is an executive file that stores in `ruby_destination/bin` folder. This is a Ruby file generated by RubyGems.

And this files calls for another Gem called [Railties](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/railties) that can be installed in the same `bin` folder, or in the `Gems` folder, that can be found by a `bundle show --paths` command. Here it is [this executable](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/exe/rails) file that is called from `rails`.

So the journey begins from the `require "rails/cli"` of the [Railties](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/railties).