# Where is the pattern of code that creates ruby/bin/rails file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Today I worked with the way a system executes `rails` command. And discovered this chain

`ruby_instalation_dir/bin/rails` -> [ruby/gems/reilaties/exe/rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/exe/rails) -> [ruby/gems/reilaties/lib/rails/cli.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/cli.rb)

Last two elements of this chain I able to find in the GitHub.

Now I'm seeking what is the instructions that tell `RubyGem` how to generate `rails` file. I did not find any match of `railaties` in the [rails.gemspec](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/rails.gemspec) file. But some how `RubyGem` knows that need to call `railaties` gem. Where does this information stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rails` command is part of the *railties* gem, not part of the *rails* gem. Therefore, you need to look in the [railties gemspec](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/railties.gemspec#L23-L24):

```rb
s.bindir      = "exe"
s.executables = ["rails"]
```

Comment: When you run `rails new appname` rails (since Rails 4) also generates a binstub in the bin directory. You can find [the template](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b2eb1d1c55a59fee1e6c4cba7030d8ceb524267c/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/bin/rails.tt) here.

Comment: This is **Railaties** gemspec. But How does it reflects on the Rails?

Comment: It doesn't. The `rails` command is part of railties, not Rails.

Comment: This is amazing.

Comment: When you install a gem all the dependencies of the gem are also installed. So running `gem install rails` also installs railties. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/836fbf2f866ae7438548e6d6f3b2a86263ed00d9/rails.gemspec#L42